# WPF .Net Core 3 XAML Island (UWP) application abruptly closes itself

Tags: wpf, uwp, xaml-islands

Application I work on uses WPF and .Net Core 3.0 targeting Windows 1903 and up. Application has an XAML Islands with UWP's TreeControl inside WPF's Prism module View. It does loads and shows up ok. But if I do something in UWP control in XAML Islands, like moving item from one location into another, it abruptly ends itself with message:

> The program '[30572] myApp.exe' has exited with code -1073741189
>   (0xc000027b)

Here is the information I got from EventViewer/Control Panel:

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 5.0.0.23231, time stamp: 0x5d7bb0cb
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.449, time stamp: 0x9b7cd6e6
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0086b954
Faulting process id: 0x1da8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5a50a0201cbee
Faulting application path: C:\MyApp\netcoreapp3.0\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 7ea2de09-ddff-461e-8861-3c0a7a2954c1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Here is pastebin-ed detailed information from WER file:

https://pastebin.com/ZkvrgjFw

Using latest updates to Visual Studio 2019 Preview to develop application.

Comment: Can you share your code? And event log information if possible

Comment: I can not post code because it is commercial application. By checking other sources, it looks like this issue happens on different installations (and different runtimes installed). However this happens even on machine on which I develop and run code, so it is not related to installed components.

Comment: It looks like TreeView control in WPF'es XAML island crashes when it tries to show tooltip on dragging items inside TreeView?

Comment: More details here, but still no reply from anyone in MSFT. https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/211

Comment: More information from Windbg: https://pastebin.com/qYGC10rD